# How do I access JWT from header?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to get access to the token value stored with the cookie.

```
[Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '20',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    cookie: 'undefined=undefined; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MWFjNTZkYjMzN2UzMzQxM2M4YjNjNDYiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzg4NjUwNzUsImV4cCI6MTYzODk1MTQ3NX0.K03ISYNiTjZitr74H1-cN1CRTsEbJbO6sVh-XqAF1bA'
  },
```

I've tried `res.cookie` but all it returned was undefined. I tried it again to get the value for 'host' but that also returned undefined. For some context, I am trying to store a JWT inside of a cookie and accessing the same token through and auth middleware.

```
router.post('/login', async(req,res)=>{

    const {username, email, password} = req.body;
    
    try{
      const user = await User.findByCredentials(username, password);
      const token = await user.generateAuthToken();

     
      res.cookie('token', token);

      console.log('generated token: ',token);

      res.redirect('/');

    }catch(e)
    {
      console.log('it did not work: ', e);

    }

  });
```

In here I am trying to access the value but I am having a hard time

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');

const auth =  async(req, res, next) =>{
    console.log('response data from auth.js: ',req)
}


module.exports = auth;
```

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes after I posted this I figured it out. I thought I was using cookie-parser but I wasn't. I required it in the app.js file but didn't require it in the router.js file.

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const {localDB,productionDB} = require('./db/mongoose');
const userRouter = require('./routes/router')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


localDB();

app.use(userRouter);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Router.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _ = require('lodash');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const router = new express.Router();
const {Item, itemsSchema}  = require('../models/items');
const List = require('../models/list');
const User = require('../models/user');
```